# How give tick interval for each hour of the day in jqplot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

In the below code, i have value at some hours of the given dates. I need 24 points per each day(per hour). So here my graph should have 2 parts(for 2 days) and each part should have 24 points even though some hours have no data. Now its showing the time interval between '2013-10-15 4:00' and '2013-10-16 11:00' ie starting from the 4th hour of first day and ending with the 11th hour of second day. How can I change my graph like so? Give me a solution please

```
  line1=[['2013-10-15 4:00',4], ['2013-10-15 6:00',6.5], ['2013-10-16 9:00',5.7], ['2013-10-16 11:00',9]];


        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
            title:'Server Activity',
            axesDefaults: {
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
                tickOptions: {
                    fontFamily: 'Georgia',
                    fontSize: '10pt',
                    angle: -40
                }
            },
            series:[{lineWidth:1}],
            rendererOptions: {
                smooth: true
            },
            gridPadding:{right:35},
            axes:{
                xaxis:{
                    renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer, tickOptions:{
                        //                                formatString:'%b %d, %Y %H:00',
                        formatString:'%b %d, %Y %H:00',
                        tickOptions: {
                            mark: 'outside',    // Where to put the tick mark on the axis
                            show: true,         // wether to show the tick (mark and label),
                            showLabel: true,    // w    ether to show the text label at the tick,
                            formatString: '',  // format string to use with the axis tick formatter
                            fontSize:11,
                            markSize: 10
                        }
                    } ,
                    tickInterval : '1 hour'
                    //numberTicks: 20

                },
                yaxis:{
                    min:0,
                    tickOptions: {
                        mark: 'inside',    // Where to put the tick mark on the axis
                        show: true,         // wether to show the tick (mark and label),
                        showLabel: true,    // wether to show the text label at the tick,
                        formatString: '%d' , // format string to use with the axis tick formatter
                        fontSize:11
                    }
                }
            },
            highlighter: {
                show: true,
                sizeAdjust: 7.5
            },
            cursor: {
                show: false
            }
            //series:[{lineWidth:2}],

        });
```